# How to normalize leading whitespace in git grep results

Tags: git

When I use `git grep` to find things, the output shows matching lines verbatim. One drawback there is that source code which is very indented will appear in the results with lots of leading whitespace, which can interfere with reading it. Another drawback is that source lines with no whitespace will have no break between the filename/line-number and the actual code, which can interfere with copying that bit into an `open` command or a smart IDE's "fuzzy-file-open" thing.

Here's some example output demonstrating the problem:

```
$ git grep -n FilterForm
src/components/app/index.jsx:4:import FilterForm from '#/components/filter-form'
src/components/app/index.jsx:115:                       <FilterForm
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:6:export default function FilterForm({
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:39:                        className={C('FilterForm', className)}
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:42:                                className="FilterForm-form""
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:47:                                                 className="FilterForm-textLabel"
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:55:                                                 className="FilterForm-textInput"
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:65:                                        className="FilterForm-resetButton"
src/components/filter-form/index.scss:1:.FilterForm {
src/components/filter-form/index.scss:20:       .FilterForm-textLabel {
src/components/filter-form/index.scss:25:       .FilterForm-textInput {
src/components/filter-form/index.scss:40:       .FilterForm-resetButton {
```

What I would like is a way to normalize that whitespace to a single space character: inserting a space or condensing leading whitespace (whether spaces or tabs) as necessary to guarantee exactly one space after the final colon that separates the location from the source code result.

I'd also like this fix to be something I can apply through my global git config (possibly as an alias).

I've consulted the man page for `git grep`, but there's no explicit flag or configuration.

One more complication is that sometimes I don't use the `-n` flag, which means I can't always count on there being 3 colon-delimited columns (which makes life difficult for `cut`).

Here's a snippet from the above sample demonstrating what I'm hoping to get:

```
$ git grep -n FilterForm
src/components/app/index.jsx:4: import FilterForm from '#/components/filter-form'
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:6: export default function FilterForm({
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:39: className={C('FilterForm', className)}
src/components/filter-form/index.jsx:42: className="FilterForm-form""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git grep -n FilterForm | sed -e 's@\(:[0-9]\+:\) *@\1 @'
```

In the `sed` part, it replaces the first sub string that matches `:<number>:0 or more <space>` (the pattern `\(:[0-9]\+:\) *`) with `:<number>:1 <space>` (the pattern `\1` ). `\1` refers to the matched part in the brackets, `:[0-9]\+:`. Note that if the string is found in a binary, the output in `git grep` is not `<path>:<number>:<content>`.

Comment: It seems like that would be difficult to apply in a general way, and it's a real mouthful to have to type out every time. I think I'd need to create a custom bash script and set up a git alias to invoke it. As far as binaries: not a concern.